# Kernel->schedule() отрабатывает два раза. Как отдебажить, разобраться почему два раза выполняетсяс крон?

Tags: php, laravel, kernel

Есть крон класс, где вызываются все команды по времени:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('generate:slots')->cron('0 0 * * *');
        $schedule->command('send:invites')->everyTenMinutes();
        $schedule->command('send:access')->everyFifteenMinutes();
        $schedule->command('get:courses')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('get:quizzes')->hourlyAt(5);
    }
}
```

И в классе комманды происходит запись лог:

```
class GetCourses extends Command
{
    public function handle()
    {
         Log::channel('trace')
            ->info('Test. ', ['result' => [
                'file path' => __FILE__,
                'func' => __FUNCTION__,
                'class' => __CLASS__,
                'line' => __LINE__
            ]]);
    }
}
```

Если запускать вручную отработает один раз как положено `php artisan get:courses`

Результат срабатывания одинаковое время, записалось два раза:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А другие задания тоже два раза отрабатываются?

Comment: Проверьте в [процессах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548511/laravel-cron-is-running-twice) под какими пользователями запущен(ы) процесс(ы) cron(а).

Comment: перенёс на другой сервер, там отрабатывает как нужно. Это связано с сервером. Задача ещё актуальна

Comment: @Walfter другие задачи тоже по два раза отрабатывают

Comment: Если другие задачи отрабатывают тоже по 2 раза то вам уже чуть выше дали одно из актуальных решений... Второй вариант что где-то есть повторный запуск шедулера в системе